# running matlab m-file from c# console application no longer working

Tags: c#, .net, matlab

I have a c# console application.

The program is very simple. It simply opens a Matlab application & specifies the directory of the m-file I wish to run, supplying one parameter (code is below). The code in the m-file basically uploads some data to a datbase. After this an excel report is created from the data uploaded to the database.

I have this task scheduled to run at 4am. The code worked fine for the first two months. However (without any changes I'm aware of) the code is not working. I come in the morning to see that it has opened an instance of matlab & it has changed the matlab directory but it does not appeared to have run the matlab function. Its strange as the c# code then runs the excel code afterwards which reprots there is no data in the database. When I come in and run the code manually though the code works fine. I don't know what is happening or how to find out what is going on?

In windows scheduled the task has the message "the operation completed successfully. (0x0)

```
 public void CalculateFundDrift()
    {
        try
        {
            // create matlab instance
            _matlab = new MLApp.MLApp();

            // change to the directory where the function is located
            _matlab.Execute(@"cd c:\my_directory\");

            // define the output
            object result = null;

            // call the matlab function upload_data            
            _matlab.Feval("my_func_name", 0, out result, "my_para");

            // quit matlab
            Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Closing Matlab");
            _matlab.Quit();

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            _matlab.Quit();
            throw;
        }
    }
```

**Update**

One thing I do no notice when running the code is that it opens a matlab command window (looks more like a text file). In the morning when I come in its an actual matlab application that has been left open.

Comment: What happens in case of an exception? Do you write a logfile or similar? If not add writing a logfile, from my experience using Matlab via python, I expect some useful information in the exception.

Comment: yes if an exception occurs a logfile gets written to. However there doesn't appear to be an exception which confuses me even more